# how can i do this SQL query in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am new to the SQL-database, I have tables and columns as follows

**productInformation**

- productInformationID(primarykey)
- ..
- ..
- price

**product**

- productId (primary key)
- productInformationID (foreign key)
- ...
- ..

**soldProducts**

- id(primarykey)
- productID(foreignkey)
- ..

I am trying to find the sold product with the highest quantity and the total price of this sale.

According to this tables, how can I do this query in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming every record in your "soldProducts" table is a single quantity. Here you go (*in postgresql*):

1. Grouped by productID to get total quantity in soldProducts, ordered by decreasing quantity and limited to highest sum (1).
2. Select the products having highest total quantity
3. Then, a series of two joins to get to price to calculate total sale.

   ```
   SELECT max.productID, max.total_quant , p.price*max.total_quant AS total_sale FROM

      (SELECT productID, COUNT(*) as total_quant FROM soldProducts 
      GROUP BY productID HAVING COUNT(*) = 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) as total_quant FROM soldProducts GROUP BY productID ORDER BY total_quant DESC LIMIT 1)) as max

      JOIN products AS p
      ON max.productID = p.productid

      JOIN productInformation AS pi
      ON p.productInformationID = pi.productInformationID ;
   ```

Comment: thank you so much for your help.


I dont have "quantity" column in "soldProducts" table. 

But in soldProducts table, for ex: if there is 5 productID are same, that means this product sold 5 times. Is it not possible to write this query according to this system?

Comment: I have modified it as per your comment. see if it works for you. Also, edit your question too with the information you have provided to me.

Comment: I really did thank you very much. I did it with your help. Thanks.

Comment: Good to know, it worked, welcome to the community. Accept/ upvote the answer to let others in need to know that its correct and worked.